# How to install and use chemfig latex package on ec2 server?

Tags: chemfig

I want to use some extra latex package like chemfig for converting chemical latex equation into PNG image. Thanks in advance

Comment: chemfig is just one infinitesimal part of TeX and ec2 cloud server is generally off topic here however note that parts of TeX don't work well with all cloud platforms unless YOU have full rights to manipulate core permissions TeX can be served (like overleaf) but the resource overheads (return on ownership) may be high WHY is your tagline biblatex ?

Comment: hey @KJO, thanks for editing. I have a web application(PHP). I want the chemical equation to include in my pdf. so any suggestion on how to implement that?

Comment: Again your question is hazy as to exactly what level of chemfig application you require If you want a web based application best to look at 3rd party off topic products such as https://web.chemdoodle.com/installation/license/